# Upserting into Postgresql removes timezone data from timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I am trying upsert into Postgresql with this query:

```
WITH

n(unique_id, timestamp, value, flag) AS (
  VALUES ('3257220001', '2021-01-26 00:00:00+02:00', 5, 1),
  ('3257220003', '2021-01-26 00:00:00+02:00', 11.5, 1)
),

upsert AS (
  UPDATE data_observeddata o
  SET value=n.value, flag=n.flag
  FROM n WHERE o.timestamp=to_timestamp(n.timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') AND o.unique_id=n.unique_id
  RETURNING o.unique_id, o.timestamp
)

INSERT INTO data_observeddata(unique_id, timestamp, value, flag)
SELECT n.unique_id, to_timestamp(n.timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'), n.value, n.flag FROM n

WHERE (n.unique_id, to_timestamp(n.timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'))

NOT IN (SELECT unique_id, timestamp from upsert);
```

which seems to work fine. However timezone data are lost. This is what is inserted:

```
9;"3257220001";"2021-01-26 00:00:00+00";5;1
10;"3257220003";"2021-01-26 00:00:00+00";11.5;1
```

this query works:

`insert into data_observeddata (unique_id, timestamp, value, flag) VALUES ('3257220001', '2021-01-26 00:00:00+02:00', 5, 1), ('3257220003', '2021-01-26 00:00:00+02:00', 11.5, 1);`

So, there must be a problem with my upserting query. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: if I remove `to_timestamp()` I get this error: `ERROR:  column "timestamp" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type text
LINE 16: SELECT n.unique_id, n.timestamp, n.value, n.flag FROM n`

Comment: Why not use insert ... on conflict?

Comment: yes you are right. I tried but something went wrong. So I carried this query from an older version I had and modified it. I couldn't find a way to bulk upsert properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with this query. I put it here for anyone interested

```
WITH
-- write the new values
n(unique_id, timestamp, value, flag) AS (
  VALUES ('3257220001', timestamp with time zone '2021-01-26 00:00:00+02:00', 8, 1),
  ('3257220003', timestamp with time zone '2021-01-26 00:00:00+02:00', 11.5, 2)
),
-- update existing rows
upsert AS (
  UPDATE data_observeddata o
  SET value=n.value, flag=n.flag
  FROM n WHERE o.timestamp=n.timestamp AND o.unique_id=n.unique_id
  RETURNING o.unique_id, o.timestamp
)
-- insert missing rows
INSERT INTO data_observeddata(unique_id, timestamp, value, flag)
SELECT n.unique_id, n.timestamp, n.value, n.flag FROM n

WHERE (n.unique_id, n.timestamp)

NOT IN (SELECT unique_id, timestamp from upsert);
```

Comment: A shorter version: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5ddb49e024315d53b3b33d4f7c886409